# Change R plot background color based on a column values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am pretty new in ggplot and have a simple question. I am trying to color R plot background based on y values. I want this plot to have 4 background colors, and each color should cover the area while x-axis is in the range of 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% of y values. I tried to use `geom_rect` but it did not work out.

How can I do that?

```
ggplot(moma_stack, aes(x = year_created, y = nn)) +
  geom_col()
```

The plot I want to color:

[image: The plot I want to color]

Comment: From your description of the problem, I don't understand what you mean by "each color should cover the area while x-axis is in the range of 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% of y values." Are you saying you want 4 vertical background colors for each quartile of the x-axis? It would help if you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showing what you want the graph to look like and including any relevant code or data you have.

Comment: Hint: look into ‘position_fill’ and create 2d group that compliments each bar in your plot (and use ’group’).